# Select the first character before a forward slash but after any space

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string patterns which I need to match as described.

I need only the first char/digit on each of the following examples. Before the '/' and after any space:

```
12/5 <--match on 1
x23/4.5 match on x
234.5/7 match on 2
2 - 012.3/4 match on 0
```

regex something like the following is obviously not enough:

```
\d(?=\d\/))
```

**To make Clear**
I'm actauly using the regex with js split so it's some mpping function which takes each one of the strings and split it on the match. So for example  `2 - 012.3/4` would be split to `[ 2 - 0, 12.3/4]` and `12/5 to 1, [2/5]` and so on.

**See example (with non working regex) here:**

https://regex101.com/r/N1RbGp/1

Comment: How does `2 - 012.3/4` match on 0? Do you mean match character between the last space and '/'?

Comment: i mean match only 0. I need to split in that case on the 0. it's always the first character in the part up to the "/" but sometimes it can also look like this: 2 - 012.3/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a regular expression like this:

```
(?<=^|\s)[a-zA-Z0-9](?=[^\s]*[/])
```

Breaking it down:

- `(?<=^|\s)` is a zero-width (non-capturing) positive lookbehind that ensures
  that the match will begin only immediately following start-of-text or a
  whitespace character.
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]` matches a single letter or digit.
- `(?=\S*[/])` is a zero-width (non-capturing) positive lookahead that requires
  the matched letter or digit to be followed by zero or more non-whitespace characters and a *solidus* ('`/`') character.

Here's the code:

```js
const texts = [
  '12/5',
  'x23/4.5',
  '234.5/7',
  '2 - 012.3/4',
];
texts.push( texts.join(', ') );

for (const text of texts) {
  const rx = /(?<=^|\s)[a-zA-Z0-9](?=\S*[/])/g;

  console.log('');
  console.group(`text: '${text}'`);
  for(let m = rx.exec(text) ; m ; m = rx.exec(text) ) {
    console.log(`matched '${m[0]}' at offset ${m.index} in text.`);
  }
  console.groupEnd();

}
```

This is the output:

```
text: '12/5'
  matched '1' at offset 0 in text.

text: 'x23/4.5'
  matched 'x' at offset 0 in text.

text: '234.5/7'
  matched '2' at offset 0 in text.

text: '2 - 012.3/4'
  matched '0' at offset 4 in text.

text: '12/5, x23/4.5, 234.5/7, 2 - 012.3/4'
  matched '1' at offset 0 in text.
  matched 'x' at offset 6 in text.
  matched '2' at offset 15 in text.
  matched '0' at offset 28 in text.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to scan the whole document:

```
/(?<=(^|\s))\S(?=\S*\/)/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/rN08sP/1

```js
s = `12/5
x23/4.5
234.5/2
534/5.6
- 49.55/6.5
234.5/7`;

console.log(s.match(/(?<=(^|\s))\S(?=\S*\/)/g));
```

But if you want to extract that character in a short string: (did you mean there is a space in front?)

It'd be `/\s(\S)\S*\//`

```js
const arr = [
  " 12/5",
  " x23/4.5",
  " 234.5/7",
  " 2 - 012.3/4"
];

arr.forEach(s => {
  let result = s.match(/\s(\S)\S*\//);
  if (result)
    console.log("For", s, "result: ", result[1])
});
```

But if "beginning of line" is ok... so no space is needed in front, then `/(^|\s)(\S)\S*\//`:

```js
const arr = [
  "12/5",
  "x23/4.5",
  "234.5/7",
  "2 - 012.3/4"
];

arr.forEach(s => {
  let result = s.match(/(^|\s)(\S)\S*\//);
  if (result)
    console.log("For", s, "result: ", result[2])
});
```

But actually, if you don't mean literally a space but just boundary in general:

```js
const arr = [
  "12/5",
  "x23/4.5",
  "234.5/7",
  "2 - 012.3/4"
];

arr.forEach(s => {
  let result = s.match(/\b(\S)\S*\//);
  if (result)
    console.log("For", s, "result: ", result[1])
});
```

Comment: Your regex works on `" 12/5"` but not on `"12/5"` - which I think is what the OP is asking?

Comment: but he said "after any space"

Comment: This regex only works if theres a space on the start of each string which there isn't. it's "12/5" or "2 - 012.3/4"

Comment: @S.Schenk made that worked too... I thought the OP asked "after any space"

Comment: but is this to match one instance of a string and extract that character, or to keep on getting matches for the whole document?

Comment: @S.Schenk please see updated answer and https://regex101.com/r/rN08sP/1

Comment: each string by itself. it's const arr = ['12/5', '2 - 012.3/4', ... ] which I'm itereating on

Comment: @S.Schenk so does my last two versions accomplish what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The first group in this regex matches the character you're asking for:

```
([^\s])[^\s]*/
```

You could also just use:

```
[^\s]+/
```

And use the first character of the match (or perhaps you need the rest anyway).